# Linear transformation matrix $\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

If $\mathcal {A}$ : $\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^3$ is a linear transformation such that:

- $\mathcal{A}(1,1)=(0,1,2)$
- $\mathcal{A}(-1,1)=(2,1,0)$

Then the standard matrix of $\mathcal {A}$ is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\mathcal{A}(\mathbf{e_1}) = \mathcal{A}(1,0) = \dfrac12\mathcal{A}(1,1)-\dfrac12\mathcal{A}(-1,1) = (-1,0,1)$.

$\mathcal{A}(\mathbf{e_2}) = \mathcal{A}(0,1) = \dfrac12\mathcal{A}(1,1)+\dfrac12\mathcal{A}(-1,1) = (1,1,1)$.

Therefore, the matrix representation of $\mathcal{A}$ is $\begin{bmatrix} \mathcal{A}(\mathbf{e_1}) & \mathcal{A}(\mathbf{e_2}) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -1&1\\0&1\\1&1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Answer (score 2):

To complement Kenny Lau's answer, here's a longer, perhaps more routine way to do essentially the same thing. You need to find the matrix for $\mathcal{A}$ from the standard basis $B_2$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ to the standard basis $B_3$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. That is, you want,
$$\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{A}, B_2, B_3).$$
What you are given is $\mathcal{A}(1, 1)$ and $\mathcal{A}(-1, 1)$, which tells you what $\mathcal{A}$ does to the non-standard basis
$$B_2' = ((1, 1), (-1, 1)).$$
This gives us,
$$\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{A}, B'_2, B_3) = \left([\mathcal{A}(1, 1)]_{B_3} ~ | ~ [\mathcal{A}(-1, 1)]_{B_3}\right) = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 2 \\ 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 0\end{pmatrix}.$$
To get what we want, we can use a change of basis matrix. We have,
$$\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{A}, B_2, B_3) = \mathcal{M}(\mathcal{A}, B'_2, B_3)\mathcal{M}(I, B_2, B'_2) = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 2 \\ 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 0\end{pmatrix}\mathcal{M}(I, B_2, B'_2)$$
We can easily compute
$$\mathcal{M}(I, B'_2, B_2) = \left([(1, 1)]_{B_2} ~ | ~ [(-1, 1)]_{B_2}\right) = \begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$
Then $\mathcal{M}(I, B_2, B'_2)$ is the inverse of the above matrix, which we can compute by your favourite method, giving us,
$$\mathcal{M}(I, B_2, B'_2) = \begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^{-1} = \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$
Putting it all together,
$$\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{A}, B_2, B_3) = \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}0 & 2 \\ 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}-2 & 2 \\ 0 & 2 \\ 2 & 2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}-1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}.$$

---

I write this answer, certainly not because it's any quicker or any more elegant than the above answer, but it does showcase a reliable method to solve more general problems. The shorter method relies on being able to see, without too much hassle, that
\begin{align*}
(1, 0) &= \frac{1}{2}(1, 1) - \frac{1}{2}(-1, 1) \\
(0, 1) &= \frac{1}{2}(1, 1) + \frac{1}{2}(-1, 1).
\end{align*}
If the bases become longer, and less nice, then the problem essentially reduces down to inverting the change of basis matrix as above, so the longer method leads intuitively to a generally applicable method.